# How to use android to create a new page/place to check in?

Tags: android, facebook

I have a problem to create a new page/place to use my app to check in.
When I use my app to check in,it needs place_id,latitude and longitude.
If I want to create a new place name at the position where I am.
I need to create a new page like this 
[timessquarenyc](http://www.facebook.com/timessquarenyc) to get the informations which I want.
But I don't know how to use android to create a new page to check in.

Please give me your point of view.

Comment: I'm not sure what you want. Do you want to create a new Facebook page for the place that you are at? Or do you want to create a new Point on a MapActivity?

Comment: Oh,I'm so sorry that I explained my question ambiguously.What I want to do is to create the new place name to check in,not just select existent checkin places.I want to do just like facebook checkin app.I think that you said the new point on a MapActivity is possibility what I want.Thank you for your reply:)

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want more is something like an 'Overlay for interesting places' (how Google calls it), like shown in [this Tutorial](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-mapview.html).

Comment: Oh~I just want to do like "touch.facebook.com".You can use it to create the new place name at the same position.I want to do like this and can use my app to add a new place name which I create to check in.